# How can I access collections in an object generated by xml2js

Tags: javascript, xml

Given the following simple XML:

```
<root>
<node1>
    <node2>
        <node3 name="blah" />
        <node3 name="blah" />
        <node3 name="blah" />
    </node2>
    <node2>
        <node3 name="blah" />
        <node3 name="blah" />
        <node3 name="blah" />
    </node2>
    <node2>
        <node3 name="blah" />
        <node3 name="blah" />
        <node3 name="blah" />
    </node2>
</node1>
```

And the following javascript:

```
xml2js.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {

                console.log(result);

                console.log(result.root);
                console.log(result.root.node1);
                // console.log(result.root.node1.node2);

                // console.log(result.root.node1.node2[1]);

//                console.log(result.root.node1[2]);

  //              console.log(result.root.node1[2]);


            }
```

How does one get at the collection of children nodes named node2 (and node3 for that matter)? None of the commented out attempts above which I thought seemed common sense work, and surprisingly there doesn't seem to be a single xml2js example which actually covers accessing it's generated output.

Output of JSON.stringify(result)

```
{
"root": {
    "node1": [
        {
            "node2": [
                {
                    "node3": [
                        {
                            "$": {
                                "name": "blah"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$": {
                                "name": "blah"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$": {
                                "name": "blah"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "node3": [
                        {
                            "$": {
                                "name": "blah"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$": {
                                "name": "blah"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$": {
                                "name": "blah"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "node3": [
                        {
                            "$": {
                                "name": "blah"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$": {
                                "name": "blah"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$": {
                                "name": "blah"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))` and show the result to us. Or what are you currently getting for your `console.log(result);`? Show us that, not the input xml.

Comment: Updated as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does one get at the collection of children nodes named node2?

`result.root.node1` is an array, to get the first `<node1>` in it you have to access it's index:

```
result.root.node1[0].node2
```

> and node3 for that matter?

There is not a single collection of `<node3>`s, but you can similarly to above access them as `.node3` of the respective i-th `.node2`:

```
result.root.node1[0].node2[i].node3
```

You might use a loop over the `<node2>` collection.

Comment: Thank you, it was as simple as that in the end. I got mixed up with Node1 being an array, as there is only ever 1 instance of it in my xml document so it seems pointless for xml2js to make it an array. But anyhow, good to know for the future.

Comment: Yeah, the conversion algorithm is a bit odd. Looks like every node consist of something like `getChildrenByTagName()` for every child tag name.